# Error mesage '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, command

My node version is `16.14.0`. I have created a react app.

In the `package.json` file, I have the following script:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "loc": "./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd -f ./envs/.env-local react-scripts start",
    "stage": "./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd -f ./envs/.env-staging react-scripts start"
  },
```

In the same folder where the `package.json` resides, there is a folder called `envs` which contain env files with names like this:- `.env-staging`, `.env-local`, etc.

In the command prompt, when I am entering

```
npm run stage
```

I am getting the follwoing error

```
> parkyt-admin@1.0.0 stage
> ./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd -f ./envs/.env-staging react-scripts start

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `./node_modules/.bin/env-cmd` is a Linux/Unix command (because of the path separator being a forward slash instead of the Windows backslash). The error message you're getting is from Windows. What OS are you actually using?

Comment: @KenWhite, I am using Windows10 as OS. Then how shall I rewrite it?